# ddev: change ip range of docker bridge network ddev_default

Tags: docker, networking, ip, ddev

is there a way to tell ddev not to use IP-Range `172.17.*.*` by default?
This range is already used in my network.
I already set my docker config in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to use the private range  `192.168.222.*`
The docker0 bridge is created with the 192.* address, but the docker network `ddev_default` still is on that 172.17.* range.

I am using ubuntu linux 18.04

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ip range is generated with an increment.

I deleted the network and and have ddev create a new one.

```sh
docker network remove ddev_default

ddev rm -R -O --stop-ssh-agent

ddev start
```

The next bridge got the ip `172.18.*`. ... next `172.19.*` and so on.

check the ip with:
`docker network inspect ddev_default`

Although I didn't configure an IP range, deleting the network and have docker create n new one with a different ip range solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. People have occasionally run into "Can't get public wifi to work" type problems because of conflicts like this. Your solution would solve that very quickly.